# Bootstrap ScrollSpy not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Here's the page I'm having the problem with http://intern-dev.obrary.com/manufacturer.

I'm trying to implement ScrollSpy through JavaScript.  Here's the js:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$(".scroll-area").scrollspy({target: "#myNavbar"}) 
});</script>
```

And here's the id for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="myNavbar">
```

And the target class:

```
<div class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="50">
```

Something with the implement is working because after I added the above the FAQ link in the navbar got the the active treatment.  But the active does not change to any of the other navbar elements.

Comment: I don't find your reference to jQuery on your website. ScrollSpy can't work without it. Add reference to jQuery in your website :

    `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation has revealed the problem.  The ScrollSpy class must go on the body.  Here's what the body looks like now:

```
  <body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
```

I had made a  within  where the class and data-spy where placed.  I did this because the navbar was within the body and I assumed the scroll area could not also include the navbar.  But that is not the case.

So it's working now at http://intern-dev.obrary.com/manufacturer

Comment: I still have `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`error in console. If it is ok for you like that, it is up to you.

Comment: @MacKentoch - Your edit removed the explanation of how I can see that error.  Could you explain again?

Comment: Yes sure, I updated my answer. It is only suggestions to debug, feel free to get your way.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

**DECLARE jQuery before bootstrap.min.js :**

```
<!--jquery 1st, this version but your may be ok : jquery-1.11.2.min.js-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--then bootstrap-->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## DEBUG in Chrome as you asked me :

1. open debugger :

   - windows : `CONTROL+SHIFT` + `I`
   - mac: `COMMAND+ALT`+ `I`
2. go `Resources tab`
3. expand `Frame`,*then tree depends your website* ;in your website :`(manufacturer)`

   - you see scripts, css loaded
4. use console (it show error...)

   - tab `console`

*As I said earlier, I prefer `Chrome` but other navigators could be good it is up to you.*

Comment: Line 81 in view source has: <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script> Is the version too old?  Or is the version in the filename throwing off jquery.min.js search.

Comment: `DECLARE jQuery before bootstrap.min.js ` this is the most Important things! thank you `MacKentoch`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if an ID begins with an underscore (and perhaps this is true for other special characters) then scrollspy does not work.  I was able to get it working by removing the underscore from my links.

**does not work:**
    `<h1 id="_Toc423191681">Leasing</h1>`
**works:**
   `<h1 id="Toc423191681">Leasing</h1>`